# Space added in a text field

Tags: php, html, whitespace

I have a problem with an input type text.

The value of the field is affected by PHP, like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ClientName" id="ClientName" value="<?php echo strtoupper($Client['name']).' '.trim($Client['surname']); ?>" />
```

Each time i have a space added at the end of the string, so when i save datas in my db with htmlentities() function, i have for example:

```
NAME Surname&nbsp;
```

I tried a lot of things, i'm sure my data from PHP don't have a space at the end. When i save datas in db, i make a TRIM on this input.

I can't remove this space and i don't know where it comes from!!

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Check value of `strtoupper($Client['name']).' '.trim($Client['surname'])` using `var_dump()`

Comment: Or just `trim()` before saving to DB

Comment: no space! var_dump($patients['nom']); and var_dump($patients['prenom']);

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's what i do, a trim before saving to DB and a trim before display in the input.

Comment: @Alexking2005 '&nbsp' is an non breakable space. Its an HTML hard space. Just replace it and send to DB.

Comment: Here is, what i do on this input before saving it:
$Clientname= trim($_POST['Clientname']);
                $Clientname= trim ($Clientname, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
                $p['Clientname'] = htmlentities(addslashes(strip_tags($Clientname)));

Comment: And it save NAME surname&nbsp;

Comment: Are you sure it's not `"NAME "`  AS in `strtoupper('NAME').' '.trim('')`  Basically if you have an empty surname, you add a space after name you never trim.  You should do `trim(strtoupper('NAME').' '.'')`

Comment: i always have a surname.